upload a file to nexus that has special characters in it (%)
Using curl, I have tried to upload a file that has multiple '%' signs in it's name. From what I understand, nexus doesn't support file paths that has special characters in them (&,%,?). Is there any workaround for this issue?
the bash command I used to upload to nexus:
curl -i -o tmp -w %{http_code} -u XXX:123 --upload-file config "https://nexus3.ourdomain.com/repository/our-repo/X/Y/Z/A%B%C/config"
